# Facing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, opends

Facing Null pointer exception while compiling.

```
public class LDAP_MultiUser_Copy1 {
    public static String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    public static String MY_HOST = "ldap://singh.plm.com:3890";

    public static String MY_SEARCHBASE = "cn=Public,x=X-Y,ou=people,cn=Windchill_8.0,cn=Application Services,x=x-y";
    public static String MY_FILTER = "(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=";
    public static String MGR_DN = "cn=Manager";
    public static String MGR_PW = "ldapadmin";
    //public String[] MY_FILTER2=new String[200];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] MY_FILTER2=new String[900];
        String[] First_Name=new String[200];
        //String[] MY_FILTER2=null;
    try{
        String fileName="C:\\report\\report.txt";
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
        String line;

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\report\\report11.csv");
        PrintWriter pwr = new PrintWriter(writer);

        String fileName1="C:\\report\\report1.txt";
        FileReader inputFile1 = new FileReader(fileName1);
        BufferedReader bufferReader1 = new BufferedReader(inputFile1);
        String line1;



        int i=0;
        while (((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) && (line1 = bufferReader1.readLine())!= null)
        {
            //System.out.println(line);
            //System.out.println("Reading text file");
            MY_FILTER2[i]=line;
            //System.out.println("My_Filter2="+MY_FILTER2[i]);


            //First_Name = line.split(",");

            //System.out.println("MAking my_filter_final");
        String MY_FILTER_Final=MY_FILTER+line+"))";
        //System.out.println("MY_FILTER_Final="+MY_FILTER_Final);


    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,INITCTX);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,MY_HOST);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,MGR_DN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,MGR_PW);
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
    constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    //performs the actual search
    //We give it a searchbase, a filter and the contraints containing the scope
    //of the search
    NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search(MY_SEARCHBASE,MY_FILTER_Final,constraints);
    //now stop through the search results
    //System.out.println(results);
    while(results==null)
    {
        System.out.println("**************************************"+line+"$$$$$does not exit in USerlist");
    }
    while(results != null || results.hasMore()){
        System.out.println("entering wile loop----------------");
    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)results.next();
    String dn = sr.getName();
    String state = dn.substring(dn.indexOf("cn=")+3);
    //String First_Name_Final=First_Name[i].substring(First_Name[i].indexOf("cn=")+3);

    //System.out.println("Username="+line1+"@@@@@@@"+line+" Group = "+state);
    System.out.println("Username="+line1+"-->Group = "+state);
    pwr.print(line1);
    pwr.print(",");
    pwr.print(state);
    pwr.print(",");
    pwr.println("");
    i++;
    Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
    NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();



    if (attrs == null) {
        System.out.println("Entry " + dn + " has none of the specified attributes\n");
        return;
      }

    }
        }   
        pwr.close();    
    }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);

    }
    }
    }
```

Facing Null Pointer Exception in while (((line = bufferReader.readLine()) !=
line. When the user belongs to no group it hits a null pointer exception.
What is want is When user belongs to no group it should return Doesn't exist .

OUTPUT:-

```
entering wile loop----------------
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.nextAux(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.nextImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.AbstractLdapNamingEnumeration.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.LDAP_MultiUser_Copy1.main(LDAP_MultiUser_Copy1.java:89)
```

Comment: which is your **line number 89** ?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Line number 89. SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)results.next();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.naming.directory.*;
    public class LDAP_MultiUser_Copy1 {
    public static String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    public static String MY_HOST = "ldap://singh.plm.com:3890";

    public static String MY_SEARCHBASE = "cn=Public,x=X-Y,ou=people,cn=Windchill_8.0,cn=Application Services,X=X-Y";

    public static String MY_FILTER = "(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=";
    public static String MGR_DN = "cn=Manager";
    public static String MGR_PW = "ldapadmin";
    //public String[] MY_FILTER2=new String[200];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] MY_FILTER2=new String[900];
        String[] First_Name=new String[200];
        //String[] MY_FILTER2=null;
    try{
        String fileName="C:\\report\\report.txt";
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
        String line;

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\report\\report11.csv");
        PrintWriter pwr = new PrintWriter(writer);

        String fileName1="C:\\report\\report1.txt";
        FileReader inputFile1 = new FileReader(fileName1);
        BufferedReader bufferReader1 = new BufferedReader(inputFile1);
        String line1;

        pwr.print("User");
        pwr.print(",");
        pwr.print("Group Name");
        pwr.print(",");
        pwr.println();

        int i=0;
        while (((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) && (line1 = bufferReader1.readLine())!= null)
        {
            //System.out.println(line);
            //System.out.println("Reading text file");
            MY_FILTER2[i]=line;
            //System.out.println("My_Filter2="+MY_FILTER2[i]);


            //First_Name = line.split(",");

            //System.out.println("MAking my_filter_final");
        String MY_FILTER_Final=MY_FILTER+line+"))";
        //System.out.println("MY_FILTER_Final="+MY_FILTER_Final);


    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,INITCTX);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,MY_HOST);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,MGR_DN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,MGR_PW);
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
    constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    //performs the actual search
    //We give it a searchbase, a filter and the contraints containing the scope
    //of the search
    NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search(MY_SEARCHBASE,MY_FILTER_Final,constraints);
    //now stop through the search results
    System.out.println(results);



    if((results.hasMore())==false)
    {
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%No Group Presnt for the USer="+line1);
        pwr.print(line1);
        pwr.print(",");
        pwr.print("No Org Group");
        pwr.print(",");
        pwr.println();
    }

    while(results != null && results.hasMore()){
        System.out.println("entering wile loop----------------");


        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)results.next();
        if(sr==null)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }

    /*  if((SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)results.next())==null)
        {
            System.out.println("No Org Group");
            pwr.print(line1);
            pwr.print(",");
            pwr.print("No Org Group");
            pwr.print(",");
            pwr.println("");
        }*/
        else
    {
    String dn = sr.getName();
    String state = dn.substring(dn.indexOf("cn=")+3);
    //String First_Name_Final=First_Name[i].substring(First_Name[i].indexOf("cn=")+3);

    //System.out.println("Username="+line1+"@@@@@@@"+line+" Group = "+state);
    System.out.println("Username="+line1+"-->Group = "+state);
    pwr.print(line1);
    pwr.print(",");
    pwr.print(state);
    pwr.print(",");
    pwr.println("");
    i++;
    Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
    NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();
    /*while(ne.hasMoreElements()) {
    Attribute attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
    String attrID = attr.getID();
    System.out.println(attrID+" :");
    Enumeration vals = attr.getAll();
    while(vals.hasMoreElements() ) {
    System.out.println("\t"+vals.nextElement());
    }
    }*/
    //System.out.println("\n");

    if (attrs == null) {
        System.out.println("Entry " + dn + " has none of the specified attributes\n");
        return;
      }

    }
        }   
        }

        pwr.close();    
    }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the answer to you question? If so please explain what you did to solve your problem, else if you want to make changes to your question use edit link in the question and update your question.

Comment: I was facing null pointer exception in line:- SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)results.next();  so i needed to ensure that SearchResult is not passed null value so  if((results.hasMore())==false)
    {....} this loop handles the cases where it can pass null value to SearchResult. Hence SearchResult doesn't face null value. Hence the exception doesn't arise. Its doing the task i need it do

Comment: add the explanation in the answer instead of adding in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

From code perspective, `while(results != null || results.hasMore()){` should be `while(results != null && results.hasMore()){`. Otherwise, it is very likely to lead to an NPE if `results` has no element.

Comment: Actually you are correct. But in this case I am trying to arrest case where SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)results.next(); can not find a result. In that case I need to know That no result has been found. It just skips and moves to new query. How to find the users for which no group is returned?